# ThreeJS Globe z-index issue

Tags: three.js, z-index, webgl-globe

I'm trying to display a Globe with points on it that open a card when clicked.
I kinda try different approaches and came up to this result : http://lefutoir.fr/timac/v1.html#

I'll need to put an HD texture of course but my main issue is that I have z-index issues. When I open some cards they are below other because of a z-index passed when they are created. I can't find any way to get control on that z-index to make it super high when I open a card.

If anyone there could have an idea that would be awesome. Tell me if you need the code I'll copy there but it's quite long.

Thanks a lot !

I want to make the open card on top of the other dots.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a third-party library called `three-globe`, so it's hiding a lot of the mechanisms from you. I recommend you build your `CSS3DObjects` so you have more control over them, [like in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css#css3d_periodictable).

The problem you're encountering is that each dot has its own card, so when you open a card, it will almost always have subsequent dots on top of it, regardless of Z-indexing:

```html
<dot>
    <card>
</dot>
<dot>
    <card>
</dot>
<dot>
    <card>
</dot>
```

What you should do is create all the dots first, and then the cards, so the cards will always be displayed on top.

```html
<dot />
<dot />
<dot />
<card />
<card />
<card />
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah I tried at first to use globe but find it limitating so I mixed stuffs and it was almost there. I don't know if I'll manage to place all my points and stuff so easily without it.